# Sending Periodic CAN signals on button press using CAPL and CANalyzer

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, canalyzer

I am trying to send a set of CAN frames on to CAN bus. I am using CAPL to program and CANalyzer8.5 to simulate and Panel designer to create a button. My requirement is to first create a button using PANEL designer. Only on button press it should start sending periodic CAN frames on to the bus. I am a bit confused as to how to achieve it. So far I have managed to write two separate programs using CAPL. First program sends data at start periodically. Second code sends data only once when the button is pressed. I want to merge both the codes to start sending periodically on button press.

first code

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{
}

variables
{
  msTimer mytimer;
  message 0x100 A={dlc=8};
  message 0x200 B={dlc=8};
  message 0x300 C={dlc=8};
  message 0x400 D={dlc=8};
}

on start
{
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}

on timer mytimer
{
  A.byte(0)=0x64;
  B.byte(4)=0x32;
  C.byte(6)=0x20;
  D.byte(7)=0x80;
  output(A);
  output(B);
  output(C);
  output(D);
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}
```

Second Code

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{
}

variables
{

  message 0x100 A={dlc=8};
  message 0x200 B={dlc=8};
  message 0x300 C={dlc=8};
  message 0x400 D={dlc=8};
}


on sysvar test::myButton
{
  A.byte(0)=0x64;
  B.byte(4)=0x32;
  C.byte(6)=0x20;
  D.byte(7)=0x80;
  output(A);
  output(B);
  output(C);
  output(D);
}
```

So as mentioned, when i press the button, it should start sending the CAN frames periodically.
But the problem is,i cannot call a function within function as below:

```
on start
{
    on sysvar test::myButton
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

please advice me. thank you

Answer (score 3):

The *on start* event is only called once at measurement start, *on sysvar* is also an event, just that in your case it gets called when you press a certain button.

Maybe try this:

```
variables
{
  msTimer mytimer;
  message 0x100 A={dlc=8};
  message 0x200 B={dlc=8};
  message 0x300 C={dlc=8};
  message 0x400 D={dlc=8};
}

on start // This only gets called once at measurement start
{
  A.byte(0)=0x64;
  B.byte(4)=0x32;
  C.byte(6)=0x20;
  D.byte(7)=0x80;
}

on sysvar test::myButton  // Starts the timer when button is pressed
{
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}

on timer mytimer
{
  output(A);
  output(B);
  output(C);
  output(D);
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}
```

However at some point you probably want to stop the timer again using the function *cancelTimer* maybe with the use of a different button or a press of a key.
For more examples, take a look at the CAPL Section in the CANalyzer Help.

Comment: In addition, without calling output A B C and D in `on sysvar test::myButton` frames will be sent out after 50 ms (when the time expires for the first time). You might also want to `setTimer()` before `output` to avoid unnecessary delays.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is -
First,  set a periodic timer at 50ms. on Button Press.
Second, output message on the timer event(50ms periodic).
So your code should be like this-

```
variables
{
  msTimer mytimer;
  message 0x100 A={dlc=8};
  message 0x200 B={dlc=8};
  message 0x300 C={dlc=8};
  message 0x400 D={dlc=8};
}

//This only gets called once at the measurement start because you want to send the same value in each period.
on start
{
  A.byte(0)=0x64;
  B.byte(4)=0x32;
  C.byte(6)=0x20;
  D.byte(7)=0x80;
}

on sysvar test::myButton  // Starts the timer when button is pressed
{
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}

on timer mytimer
{
  output(A);
  output(B);
  output(C);
  output(D);
  setTimer(mytimer,50);
}
```